# What should we do if a user wants to create a new tag and apply it to old questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This question is prompted by the creation of the [inverted-flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverted-flight) and its addition to a few old questions.

This has raised a few eyebrows, since the actions basically swamped the homepage for a while. (This is the result of the edits mixed with the fact that we don't have a huge amount of traffic, meaning that edited posts tend to stay on the homepage for a while)
Moreover, some think that the tag might not be useful/necessary.

So, this brings us to the question: as a community, what is the preferred way in which we would like users to proceed, if they think a new tag is needed on several old questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personal opinion follows.

given our traffic volume, we had already in the past issues with users swamping the homepage with edits, effectively hiding new questions.

For this I propose that:

- we should not accept more than 2-3 edits in a row (this is easily spotted on the main page, as the editor nickname appears next to the question)
- new tags should be first discussed on meta, to avoid edit wars between people that think the tags are useful and people that think the opposite.

Comment: I'm with you, with just one addition that doesn't warrant me posting a separate answer. Discuss the new tag in chat first, as there's more traffic there than here. And 2-3 edits per day is already the established etiquette as far as I know.

Comment: @ymb1 or for better effect, create the post on the meta first, then promote the link on the chat.

Comment: @ymb1 I think meta is better than chat for this. Chat tends to hide the topic after some discussion, and not everyone is around all day. Meta has a broader audience, as well as making the topic stay.

Comment: Definitely meta, not chat for the main proposals. Of course, people are welcome to chat about anything they want and chat can be a great place to hash out ideas before posting them here.

Comment: By "2-3 edits in a row", do you mean generally, or "edits under 2-3 unique questions in a row"? The latter is what appears as 2-3 edits in the homepage... maybe it's too late to ask this now. :P

Comment: @EKons no, it is not too late. I'd hope that a person would not start editing multiple times the same post, so I am referring to 2-3 questions being edited.